# Run a function if a button has ever been clicked, even on page reload

Tags: javascript, html, button, cookies, local-storage

I have a button:

```
<script>
function never(){
alert('This is place holding text');
}
</script>
<button onclick="never()">Understood</button>
```

I need to use local storage or cookies to remember if the button has ever been clicked, and if it has, to run the function and if it hasn't to not run the function until they click the button, I've had an idea...

1. Onload Run Function.
2. Check if button has been clicked, then run function.
3. Else do not run function.
4. If button is clicked set cookie or value to run function automatically now.

I have no idea how to actually implement this though, or if this won't work. And yes, I know the real solution would be server side, but I do not have a server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this [implementation](https://jsbin.com/wepalezuti/edit?html,js,output)

You can just store some value to `localStorage` when clicked and then `read` those values later.

**HTML**

```
<button id="btn">Click Me</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
const btn = document.querySelector("#btn");

if(localStorage.getItem('clicked')) btn.innerText = 'clicked once';


btn.addEventListener('click', handleClick);

function handleClick(event) {
  if(localStorage.getItem('clicked')) return;
  else {
    localStorage.setItem('clicked', true);
    btn.innerText = 'clicked once';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**do u mean this way :**

```
<button onclick="run()">Click</button>
function run(){
localStorage.setItem('item','value');
}
```

or something else ??

Answer (score 0):

#### or try this way

```js
var someData = 'any data.';
localStorage.setItem('myData', '') 
function never(){
   localStorage.setItem('myData', someData); 
   alert('This is place holding text');
}
var data = localStorage.getItem('myData');
 if (data != ""){
   never()
 }
localStorage.removeItem('myData')
```

```html
<button onclick="never()">Understood</button>
```